# ORDER BY issue with GROUP BY and JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all apologies for the newbee question, I am pretty new to MySQL.

I have 3 tables for a simple photo contest:

registrations:

```
ID
UserName
name
LastName
Email
Mobile
```

photogallery:

```
ID
ImageName
user_id
Status=1
```

photovote:

```
Photo_ID
Date
Time
Status
```

I need to count the votes for each photo on a give time slice, and in case of tie I need to check the one that received the last vote first.

The query I came up with is:

```
SELECT      v.Photo_ID AS "Photo ID",
        g.ImageName AS "Photo URL",
        r.UserName AS "Username",
        r.name AS "Name",
        r.LastName AS  "Surname",
        r.Email AS "E-Mail",
        r.Mobile AS "Phone",
        v.Date AS "Last Vote Date",
        v.Time AS "Last Vote Time",
        COUNT(Photo_ID) AS "Total Votes"
FROM photovote v
    INNER JOIN photogallery g ON v.Photo_ID = g.ID
        INNER JOIN registration r ON g.user_id = r.ID

WHERE v.Status =1
AND g.Status =1

AND v.Date >20130728
AND v.Date <20130805

GROUP BY 1

ORDER BY 10 DESC, 8 DESC, 9 DESC
```

Nevertheless the ORDER BY is not working correctly. Any hint is highly apreciated.

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly"?

Comment: Shouldn't your order by statements be a column name rather than a number?

Comment: @DavidMacCrimmon when debugging, it's often quicker to use positional fields in the `order by`, however these should be removed before making its way to production

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan here is some [sample data](http://www.modamusic.it/files/sampledata.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I need to count the votes for each photo on a give time slice, and in case of tie I need to check the one that received the last vote first.*

Just to get photo_ids sorted by votes and lastVote Time:

```
select Photo_ID, count(*) as votes, max(Timestamp(Date,Time)) as lastVoteTime 
from photovote 
where Date > [start] and Date < [end] and status = 1
group by Photo_ID 
order by votes desc, lastVoteTime asc;
```

You can join the result of this query with other tables to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does perfectly the job!
For those who care the resulting full query is as follows:

Comment: `SELECT  v.Photo_ID AS "Photo ID",
 count(v.Photo_ID) as "Total Votes",
        g.ImageName AS "Photo URL",
        r.UserName AS "Username",
        r.name AS "Name",
        r.LastName AS "Surname",
        r.Email AS "E-Mail",
        r.Mobile AS "Phone",
  max(Timestamp(v.Date,v.Time)) AS "Last Vote Time",
        COUNT(Photo_ID) AS "Total Votes"
FROM photovote v
    INNER JOIN photogallery g ON v.Photo_ID = g.ID
        INNER JOIN registration r ON g.user_id = r.ID

WHERE v.Status =1
AND g.Status =1

AND v.Date >20130728
AND v.Date <20130805

GROUP BY 1

ORDER BY 10 DESC, 9`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your ORDER BY with this one:

```
ORDER BY `Last Vote Time` DESC, `Last Vote Date` DESC, `Total Votes` DESC;
```

You need to use back-ticks due to the " " (space) character. Also the ordering of the ORDER BYs makes a difference.

Also, you will need to include more fields into your GROUP BY otherwise data will be lost in MYSQL (other DBMSs would make your query invalid).

Add these to your GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY v.Photo_id, `Last Vote Date`,`Last Vote Time`
```

(If anything else changes over time (e.g. name) then this may cause problems later - but that is a separate matter)

Comment: Not working either. What I get is the first vote cast for each photo, not the last. The strange thing is that if I remove the last 2 DESC it shall affect only the date/time sort, instead it shows the exact same values in the exact same order..

Comment: @AndreaCorelli See my updates - it's about the ordering - also toy with the ASC depending on what you actually need.

Comment: According to your changes, if I understand it correct it shall show the data sorted by the latest comment of the last date and then by total votes. This is not actually happening. I think the key point lies in the fact that the sorting by date and time shall be done before the grouping, maybe the query is totally wrong.

Comment: @AndreaCorelli Ok, see the newest update - you were right in feeling odd about the GROUP BY. I should have looked at your code more carefully.

Comment: @d'alar'cop sorry, this is not working either. The GROUP BY function structured this way results in a list of the votes.